# How to prove via induction.

Tags: induction, proof-explanation

How would you prove (using induction) that:

(If $f(1) = 1996$)

$f(n) = \frac{1}{(2^{2} - 1)} \cdot \frac{2^2}{(3^{2} - 1)} \cdot \frac{3^2}{(4^2 - 1)} \cdot ... \cdot \frac{(n-1)^2}{n^{2} - 1} \cdot f(1)$  given that $f(1) + f(2) + f(3) + f(4) + ... + f(n)= n^2 f(n)$ and that $f$ is defined for all positive integers $n>1$?

Comment: How is f(1) defined? I assume 1?

Comment: Oh sorry f(1) = 1996

Comment: But then it's false: $f(1)+f(2)=4f(2)$, hence $f(2)=1996/3$, which is not the case by the first formula

Comment: Sorry see edit.

Comment: Can you please add some context: where does this problem come from?

Comment: 32nd British Math Olympiad 1996 (Problem 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Induction base holds, let's prove induction step.

Assume that holds $$f(n) = \frac{1}{(2^{2} - 1)} \cdot \frac{2^2}{(3^{2} - 1)} \cdot \frac{3^2}{(4^2 - 1)} \cdots \frac{(n-1)^2}{n^{2} - 1} \cdot f(1).$$
We have by our formula that $$(n+1)^2f(n+1)=f(1)+\dots+f(n)+f(n+1)=n^2f(n)+f(n+1),$$ from where we get
$$((n+1)^2-1)f(n+1)=n^2f(n)$$ and $$f(n+1)=\frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2-1}f(n).$$
By using our assumption, we get $$f(n+1)=\frac{1}{(2^{2} - 1)} \cdot \frac{2^2}{(3^{2} - 1)} \cdot \frac{3^2}{(4^2 - 1)} \cdots\frac{(n-1)^2}{n^{2} - 1}\frac{(n+1-1)^2}{(n+1)^2-1} \cdot f(1).$$

Answer (score 0):

Given that:
$f(1) = 1996$ and
$f(1) + f(2) + f(3) + f(4) + ... + f(n)= n^2 f(n)$

Prove by induction:

$f(n) = \frac{1}{(2^{2} - 1)} \cdot \frac{2^2}{(3^{2} - 1)} \cdot \frac{3^2}{(4^2 - 1)} \cdot ... \cdot \frac{(n-1)^2}{n^{2} - 1} \cdot f(1)$

base case $n=2$

$1996 + f(2) = 2^2 f(2)\\
(2^2 - 1) f(2) = 1996\\
f(2) = \frac 1{2^2+1} f(2)$

Inductive hypothesis:

Assume
$f(n) = \frac{1}{(2^{2} - 1)} \cdot \frac{2^2}{(3^{2} - 1)} \cdot \frac{3^2}{(4^2 - 1)} \cdot ... \cdot \frac{(n-1)^2}{n^{2} - 1} \cdot f(1)$

We must show that

$f(n+1) = \frac{1}{(2^{2} - 1)} \cdot \frac{2^2}{(3^{2} - 1)} \cdot \frac{3^2}{(4^2 - 1)} \cdot ... \cdot \frac{(n-1)^2}{n^{2} - 1}\cdot \frac{(n)^2}{(n+1)^{2} - 1} \cdot f(1)$

Based on the inductive hypothesis.

$f(1) + f(2) + f(3) + f(4) + ... + f(n) + f(n+1)= (n+1)^2 f(n+1)\\
f(1) + f(2) + f(3) + f(4) + ... + f(n)= ((n+1)^2 -1) f(n+1)\\
n^2 f(n)= ((n+1)^2 -1) f(n+1)\\
n^2\frac{1}{(2^{2} - 1)} \cdot \frac{2^2}{(3^{2} - 1)} \cdot \frac{3^2}{(4^2 - 1)} \cdot ... \cdot \frac{(n-1)^2}{n^{2} - 1} \cdot f(1)=((n+1)^2 -1) f(n+1)\\
f(n+1) = \frac{(n)^2}{(n+1)^{2} - 1} \cdot\frac{1}{(2^{2} - 1)} \cdot \frac{2^2}{(3^{2} - 1)} \cdot \frac{3^2}{(4^2 - 1)} \cdot ... \cdot \frac{(n-1)^2}{n^{2} - 1} \cdot f(1)$

QED

Answer (score 0):

Suppose it is true for $n \in \Bbb N$. Then 
$$n^2f(n)+f(n+1)=f(1)+...+f(n)+f(n+1)=(n+1)^2f(n+1) \iff f(n+1) = \frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2-1}f(n)$$